# how to add value to array in the next postion

Tags: c#

i am building a small app that act like a digital camera, and on my takephoto function i want to insert a random number to my array(i succeed doing that), my problem is that when i take multiple pictures the value always go into the first postion. my code:

```
public override void TakePhoto()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int photo = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {

        MemoryCard.buffer[i] = photo;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DigitalCamera digitalCamera = 
            new DigitalCamera("kodak", 43, newMemoryCard, 3);

        digitalCamera.TakePhoto();
        digitalCamera.TakePhoto();
        digitalCamera.TakePhoto();

    }
}
```

how do i jump to the next position after each photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following modification to your code will resolve your issue:

```
class DigitalCamera
{
    static int currentPhotoNumber = 0;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public override void TakePhoto()
    {
        int photo = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        MemoryCard.buffer[currentPhotoNumber++] = photo;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DigitalCamera digitalCamera = new DigitalCamera("kodak", 43, newMemoryCard, 3);

        digitalCamera.TakePhoto();
        digitalCamera.TakePhoto();
        digitalCamera.TakePhoto();

    }
}
```

Comment: Will always create the same "random" value.

Comment: how do i create a diffrent one each time?

Comment: Please see the edit. I think that it will generate different random numbers

Answer (score 5):

You esplicitly say to put next value in the first position.

Look on your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
   MemoryCard.buffer[i] = photo;
}
```

`i` is always `0`

To resolve this, just save an i value into some global variable, or *next index* accept like a parameter in the `TakePhoto(...)` function.

Example:

```
int curindex = 0; //GLOBAL VARIABLE 

public override void TakePhoto()
{
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int photo = rnd.Next(1, 10);
   if(curindex < MemoryCard.buffer.Length) //IF CURINDEX LESS THE TOTAL ARRAY LENGTH
   {
      MemoryCard.buffer[curindex] = photo;  //ASSIGN PHOTO IN CURRENTINDEX
      curindex ++;                          //INCEREMENT CURRENTINDEX
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You have a bug in your for-loop, i assume you want to use the `Length`  of the `buffer` variable instead
2. You are calling `TakePhoto` too fast, therefore you create the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) always with the same seed, hence always the same "random" number is generated.

Instead pass the `Random` instance as parameter to the method or use a field variable.

```
public override void TakePhoto(Random rnd)
{
    int photo = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < MemoryCard.buffer.Length; i++)
    {

        MemoryCard.buffer[i] = photo;
    }
}
```

Now always use the same instance:

```
Random r = new Random();
DigitalCamera digitalCamera = new DigitalCamera("kodak", 43, newMemoryCard, 3);
digitalCamera.TakePhoto(r);
digitalCamera.TakePhoto(r);
digitalCamera.TakePhoto(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a logic error in your code here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {

        MemoryCard.buffer[i] = photo;
    }
```

If you look at your for-loop variables, the loop is running from i=0, to i<1. Which basically means that the loop is only running once (for i=0).

You need to increase i each time, perhaps

```
 MemoryCard.buffer[MemoryCard.numberofphotos] = photo;
 MemoryCard.numberofphotos++;
```

Comment: i tried to insert a counter but because i am calling them from the main program its ignoring that.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue with Random.